# How to open file/browse dialog in ps script for .bak file selection and getting the file path of the selected .bak file

Tags: scripting

I want to open a file/browse dialog for .bak file selection so that user can browse to its .bak file and then i want to retrieve the file path of the user selected .bak file.

i am very new to PS SCRIPT .how to achieve the above task in ps script